# After adding element in NSMutableArray previous elements gets replaced

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm working on app in which I want to create array with number of NSDictionary's. When i'm trying to add NSMutableDictionary in NSMutableArray, previously added elements of that array get replaced. I don't know what is happening. Code as follows:

```
var paynowArray = NSMutableArray()
let tempDict = NSMutableDictionary()
for i in 0...selectedEmenetsArray.count-1 {
    tempDict.removeAllObjects()
    tempDict.setValue(selectedIdAry[i], forKey: "serviceId")
    tempDict.setValue(selectedAmountAry[i], forKey: "serviceAmount")              
    paynowArray.add(tempDict)
}
print(paynowArray)
```

While printing array last added NSMutableDictionary printed n times.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create tempDict inside the for loop**. You should allocate dictionary for every element. Else you are replacing the same memory location value every times.

```
var paynowArray = NSMutableArray()
for i in 0...selectedEmenetsArray.count-1 {

    var tempDict = NSMutableDictionary()

    tempDict.setValue(selectedIdAry[i], forKey: "serviceId")
    tempDict.setValue(selectedAmountAry[i], forKey: "serviceAmount")              
    paynowArray.add(tempDict)
}
print(paynowArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be inside the loop..

```
let tempDict = NSMutableDictionary()
```